# css less adding a variable to the selector

Tags: css, less

I'm a LESS newbie just trying to use it initally to remove some duplication form my stylessheets. I'm trying to add a variable to a (relatively) complex selector in less 1.2.21 using the following code:

```
@current_house_id: 97;
ul#house-family-menu li#menu-item-@current_house_id {
    background: #8cb4e8 url(images/family-current.png) no-repeat 97% 50%;
}
```

For the avoidance of doubt the original css would have been:

```
ul#house-family-menu li#menu-item-97 {
    background: #8cb4e8 url(images/family-current.png) no-repeat 97% 50%;
}
```

When I compile this with lessc I get error:

> Syntax Error: on line 268: expected one of [ ( . # * - :: : @media @font-face , { ; got @ after: ul#house-family-menu li#menu-item-

I've tried various escaping mechanisms suggested here and elsewhere but nothing seems to work, perhaphs this isn't supported in less? If it isn't I guess I could do the less equivlent of a case on ul#house-family-menu li#menu-item and apply the items one at a time?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't make too much sense to me. When does `@current_house_id` ever change? Why not use a class?

Comment: The same style sheet is used across multiple sites and several different selectors refer to the variable. In addition the id numbers are set by wordpress menu creation.

Comment: I'd still suggest you use a *class* on the element in question instead of dynamically altering the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The following:

```
@b: 3;

(~'.tester@{b}') {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Outputs:

```
.tester3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Your solution:

```
@current_house_id: 97;
(~'ul#house-family-menu li#menu-item-@{current_house_id}') {    }
```

Outputs:

```
ul#house-family-menu li#menu-item-97 {    }
```

---

**Edit:**

1.4.0-beta looks to have changed this (http://lesscss.org/):

```
(~".myclass_@{index}") { ...
```

selector interpolation is deprecated, do this instead

```
.myclass_@{index} { ....
```

---

**Additionally:**

You cannot do selector interpolation, as expected (v1.5.0 at least), if selector is a pseudo element. Open issue: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1294

Work around:

```
.myMixin(@whichPseudo) {
  @pseudo-selector: ~":@{whichPseudo}";
    &@{pseudo-selector} {
       background: red;
    }
}

#someEl1 {
    .myMixin(before);
}

#someEl2 {
   .myMixin(after);
}
```